Complexity of solving system of binary quadratic equations modulo $3$
A special case of this question and
another question

What is the complexity of solving system of binary quadratic equations modulo
$3$?

$f_i(x_i,x_j)=0 \bmod 3, \deg{f_i}=2$.
Modulo $2$ can be formulated as 2-SAT, so it is polynomial in the
number of variables.
One way to answer is to show it is NP-hard.

Note that $(x-y-1)(x-y-2) = 0 \leftrightarrow x \neq y$, so this is NP-complete (even with all $f_i$ equal to that) by a reduction from 3-Coloring.

Indeed, many thanks.

This also answers the first linked question, so I will accept it as answer there too.

There is stronger result: every variable occurs bounded number of times, coming from coloring bounded degree graphs.
